# Javascript in userscript/tampermonkey/greasemonkey form to perform math on HTML values

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, userscripts, tampermonkey

I am trying to write a script in tampermonkey that prints/inserts a value calculating the $ per sq ft. (Price/Total Sq Ft.) of each listing in a list like this. I have no javascript experience:

[Screen Shot Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8e1g.jpg)

Webpage:
http://www.utahrealestate.com/search/map.search

Relevant portion of HTML (one of the listings:)

```
<div id="mls-inline-1420899" class="listing_container">
        <div class="listing-wrapper-table">
            <div class="listing-wrapper-row">
                <div class="listing-container-desktop">
                    <div class="listing-wrapper-cell">
                        <img src="http://assets.utahrealestate.com/photos/280x210/1420899_6faef96a263f4613b6b300cc915a9767_710733.jpg" class="listing-img" alt="MLS #1420899 Photo">
                    </div>
                    <div class="listing-wrapper-cell aligned-top">
                        <div class="inline_info">
                            <p class="status">
                                <i class="icon icon-circle status-1"></i> Active                            </p>
                            <h3>$249,000</h3>
                            <div class="list-info-content">
                                                                    135 S 300 E                                                                <br>
                                Provo, UT 84606                            </div>
                            <div class="list-info-content">
                                5 bds •
                                2.00 ba •
                                2026 sqft<br>
                                                        Built: 1914 • MLS #: 1420899                            </div>
                            <p class="inline_agent">Agent: Chase Leavitt</p>
                            <p class="inline_brokerage">RE/MAX Equity</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="listing-container-handheld">
                    <img id="img_1420899" class="listing-img" src="http://assets.utahrealestate.com/photos/640x480/1420899_6faef96a263f4613b6b300cc915a9767_710733.jpg" alt="MLS #1420899 Photo">
                    <div class="listings-info" style="display: block;">
                        <div class="listings-info-left-col">
                            <span>$249,000</span>
                            <p class="listing-address">135 S 300 E</p>
                            <p class="listing-address-csz">Provo, UT 84606</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="listings-info-right-col">
                            <div class="border"><span>5</span><br>Beds</div>
                            <div class="border"><span>2.00</span><br>Baths</div>
                            <div class="end"><span>2026</span><br>Sq.Ft.</div>
                            <p>#1420899</p>
                        </div>
                        <p class="inline_brokerage">RE/MAX Equity</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I wrote a list of things that I need to accomplish to make this happen:

1. Javascript to grab the value of each listing and put it in a
   variable
2. Javascript to grab the sq footage of each listing while excluding the uneeded info in the same div
3. Javascript to divide those variables and store result in a $perSqFt variable
4. Javascript to output that new value along with the original data
5. Loop for all of the listings doing the same as above.

Here is what I have so far. Feel free to offer any pointers, links, or advice. I am just updating this as I go. Thank you for helping!

(#1) The value for each listing is within a h3 tag. I am thinking that I will need to use find to get the value of the h3 tag:

```
.find('h3')
```

(#4) I am thinking I can use appendChild to output the new value next to the original sq ft value. Still working on this:

```
document.getElementById('list-info-content').appendChild(dollarPerSqFt);
```

(#5) The beginnings of a loop through .list-info-content classes:

```
var find_class = document.getElementsByClassName('list-info-content');
for (var i = 0, i++) {
   find_class[i].innerHTML = {do something to} find_class[i].innerHTML ;
}
```

Comment: So, you're coming here to look for someone to do all the relevant coding for the entire project for you then, with no effort of your own? That's not really how this works.

Comment: Sorry, no, just any helpful hints to point me in the right direction would be appreciated. Also, this is just a personal project. I am currently working on this and will update with what I have momentarily.

Comment: #4 it is a class, not an id - as you did it correct in #5.